# Best way to use available bool columns in a table to generate a 'Totals' column in a SQL View?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sum, case

I have 4 columns in a Table 'Order' which are of bit datatype. I have them defined like this:

```
[IsRebate1Applicable] BIT CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_IsRebate1Applicable] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[IsRebate2Applicable] BIT CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_IsRebate2Applicable] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[IsRebate3Applicable] BIT CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_IsRebate3Applicable] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[IsRebate4Applicable] BIT CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_IsRebate4Applicable] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
```

I am trying to generate a sql view from this table which has a 'Total Rebates' column which should be the SUM of rebates that are marked true.

**Rules**:

If rebate 1 is true then 2500 else 0

If rebate 2 is true then 1000 else 0

If rebate 3 is true then 750 else 0

If rebate 4 is true then 750 else 0

**What would be an appropriate way to achieve this?**

**Can we do it using SUM & CASE in SQL?**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: 1) `BIT` is ***not*** `bool`. There is no boolean datatype in SQL and thus, there is also no "true" or "false" constants, there is only `0` and `1`.  2) Use `CASE WHEN..` expressions for multi-conditional value conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT (IsRebate1Applicable * 2500) + (IsRebate2Applicable * 1000) + (IsRebate3Applicable * 750) + (IsRebate4Applicable * 750)

This works because a bit field with 0 is false; a value of 1 is true.  So we multiple the bit field (0/1) by the amount of the rebate.